# Textbox Control in bada 1.1?

Tags: textbox, bada

Is  text box control is available in bada 2.0 only .Then how can we use control or method which can

provide the functionality similar to textbox in bada 1.1 .Is any one have idea than Kindly please suggest

me because I want to use the similar contol (textbox) functionality   in bada 1.1 .

Answer (score 0):

The docs state - since bada 2.0. So no, it's not. The straightforward downlevel alternative is `Label`, or you could create your own control based on `CustomControlBase`. if you want things like multiline text and click reactions, that's your best bet probably.